# Xtext, create independent EMF model after validation

Tags: xtext, ecore

Having a xtext plug-in defined in a DSL I want to:

- After a file is validated the xtext EMF is translated to a independent EMF model
- The independent model will be used during the code generation.

Questions:

- How to create a EMF from a ecore registered model so that the model can be be used during the code generation phase and to create a graphical representation.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably a Model-to-Model transformation, which you can specify using a variety of technologies, including Java.
After that, you can apply it to your model by any means you deem necessary, i.e. after saving, or via a contextual menu or some button in the UI.